# Java Tool Notarize process

Tags: java, macos, notarize, notary

we have developed GUI tool using Java SE 11 , packaged using Maven. Recommend user to download and set Java in system path to launch the tool. Batch file for windows and .command file for Mac and Linux. Do we need to get notarize approval from apple to use it in Mac OS. Please advice

Thanks

Comment: Not for just the script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Notarization for the script files. For your GUI Tool it highly depends on your projects dependencies. If your project only use common java packages, then everything should be fine. But there are libaries which require notarization. I personally had this issue with the `net.java.dev.jna` dependency. My experience is based on a jar bundled within an application. I am not sure if it is the same for a jar excuted from a script only. I recommend to just build your app and try to run it on a catalina machine.